# Organizing an object to create keys when needed and/or push different attribute to value pair array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

The data structure that I am trying to achieve would look as so :
I would like the list_id to become a key in a object, and hold all the id's of the items that have the matching list id.

```
var lists = { (list_id)1 : [1, 2, 3]
              (list_id)2 : [4, 5, 6]
              (list_id)3 : [7, 8, 9]
              (list_id)4 : [10, 11, 12] };
```

this object is created from a json data structure that looks like this:

```
    let json = [{ id: 1, list_id: 1 }, { id: 2, list_id: 1 }, 
                {id: 3, list_id: 1 }, {id: 4, list_id: 2 },
                {id: 5, list_id: 2 }, {id: 6, list_id: 2 },
                {id: 7, list_id: 3 }, {id: 8, list_id: 3 },
                {id: 9, list_id: 3 }, {id: 10, list_id: 4  },
                {id: 11, list_id: 4 }, {id: 12, list_id: 4 }]
```

I can make an object that holds all the list_id's as keys but am getting stumped on pushing the actions_id into the value pair array with the matching list id.

```
 let listAll = {};

 json.forEach(function(lista, index, listb) {
   listAll[lista.list_id] = [];

   if ( listAll[lista.list_id] === lista.list_id){

      listAll[lista.list_id].push(lista.id)

    } else {

      listAll[lista.list_id] = [lista.id];

    }
});
```

My goal is to have and object that contains a key for every list_id currently avaliable from the actions.
Then add every action that contains the matching list_id into a value pair array.

the current output of this code is

```
{ '1': [ 3 ], '2': [ 6 ], '3': [ 9 ], '4': [ 12 ] }
```

which does not contain all numbers, each array should contain 3 numbers.

Comment: Can you give a full example of the input that would result in the desired output you posted?

Comment: @Ele what is invalid output? I know my code is not working. Can you elaborate? 

I have updated to have the full json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try `hasOwnProperty` instead?

```
var listAll = {};
json.forEach(function(list, index) {
  if (listAll.hasOwnProperty(list.list_id)) {
    listAll[list.list_id].push(list.id);
  }else {
    listAll[list.list_id] = [list.id];
  } 
});
console.log(listAll);
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group the objects by a specific `key = ['list_id', list_id].join('')`.

```js
let json = [{ id: 1, list_id: 1 }, { id: 2, list_id: 1 },                 {id: 3, list_id: 1 }, {id: 4, list_id: 2 },                {id: 5, list_id: 2 }, {id: 6, list_id: 2 },                {id: 7, list_id: 3 }, {id: 8, list_id: 3 },                {id: 9, list_id: 3 }, {id: 10, list_id: 4  },                {id: 11, list_id: 4 }, {id: 12, list_id: 4 }],
    result = json.reduce((a, {id, list_id}) => {
      let key = ['list_id', list_id].join(''); // For example: this is creating ['list_id', 1] to list_id1
      (a[key] || (a[key] = [])).push(id);
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)/*This is only to create an object without prototype -> {}*/);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am trying to do the opposite of what your reduce function is doing..

The ouput I want to achieve is:  (list_id)1: [1, 2, 3]
I want to create that structure from the json object {id:1 list_id :1}

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the reply. 
Do you mind explaining what your join variable is doing?
Also why at the end you create a null object?

This code is very helpful to me and I would like to understand it more.